# GH001: Large Files Detected - Removed Large File and trying to save recent work

Tags: git, github, large-files

I've read several other threads relating to this same problem and everyone seems to be just going back to 'git reset --hard'… which I am trying to avoid because I will lose work between when my error began, trying to revert the commit, and removing the large file.

---

### Basically, this was my series of events:

1. Attempted to commit with a LARGE file (100mb)
2. Received Error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage
3. Deleted the large file on my desktop.
4. Continued working in same branch, and made several file changes.
5. Committed changes, received same error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage
6. $ git rm —cached large_filename.ext
7. Received error: fatal: pathspec 'large_filename.ext' did not match any files
8. Reverted original Commit with Large File
9. Attempted to commit changes
10. Same Error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage

---

### What I'm trying to accomplish (best case scenario):

1. Remove this large file from my cache without losing my current work in my HEAD
2. Commit only recent changes in my HEAD (without the large file, of course)

---

### MY ERROR: from $ git push

```
Counting objects: 57, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (53/53), done.
Writing objects: 100% (57/57), 74.03 MiB | 447.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 57 (delta 24), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (24/24), completed with 13 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage 
remote: error: Trace: #####
remote: error: See http-git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File large_filename.ext is 104.47 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To http-PROJECTNAME.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http-PROJECTNAME.git'
$ git rm --cached large_filename.ext
fatal: pathspec 'large_filename.ext' did not match any files
```

---

### A Visual representation of my Problem:

[Github vs My Git Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R52RO.jpg)

---

### UPDATE 20170303:

@Edmundo thanks for the helpful information getting me this far. I think I am getting close. I created a new branch, removed the cached files, amended, then tried to cherry-pick and it wouldn't let me merge because of the untracked working tree files would be overwritten (which is strange because I thought I removed them).

```
$ git branch gj-removehero ###6d9dc0e3983968a012ec22795dd69f7######
$ git checkout gj-removehero
Switched to branch 'gj-removehero'
$ git rm --cache assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock_276636890.*
rm 'assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock_276636890.jpg'
rm 'assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock_276636890.psd'
$ git commit --amend --no-edit
[gj-removehero b7e320b] hero options
 Date: Fri Mar 31 09:40:19 2017 -0400
 16 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock-393187381.jpg
 create mode 100644 assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock-192138551.jpg
 create mode 100644 assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock-374766055.jpg
 create mode 100644 assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock-127556570.jpg
 create mode 100644 assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock-579102199.jpg
 create mode 100644 assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock-223736014.jpg
 create mode 100644 assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock-379532248.jpg
 create mode 100644 assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock-226122967.jpg
 create mode 100644 assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock-229092871.jpg
 create mode 100644 assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock-567904627.jpg
 create mode 100644 assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock-224715364.jpg
 create mode 100644 assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock-439437442.jpg
 create mode 100644 assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock-283528433.jpg
 create mode 100644 assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock-582564463.jpg
 create mode 100644 assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock-528930796.jpg
 create mode 100644 assets/theme/img/theme-hero-05.jpg

$ git cherry-pick ###6d9dc0e3983968a012ec22795dd69f7######
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock_276636890.jpg
        assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock_276636890.psd
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
$ git rm assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock_276636890.*
fatal: pathspec 'assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock_276636890.jpg' did not match any files
$ git cherry-pick ###6d9dc0e3983968a012ec22795dd69f7######
[gj-removehero 0c808b5] hero options
 Date: Fri Mar 31 09:40:19 2017 -0400
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100755 assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock_276636890.jpg
 create mode 100644 assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock_276636890.psd
$ git rm --cache assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock_276636890.*
rm 'assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock_276636890.jpg'
rm 'assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock_276636890.psd'
$ git commit --amend --no-edit
On branch gj-removehero
Untracked files:
        assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock_276636890.jpg
        assets/theme/img/hero-ideas/shutterstock_276636890.psd

No changes
You asked to amend the most recent commit, but doing so would make
it empty. You can repeat your command with --allow-empty, or you can
remove the commit entirely with "git reset HEAD^".
```

Comment: If you remove the file on subsequent revisions, the file is still part of the history of the branch you are working on (on previous revisions). You should go to the revision where the file was added and amend it without the file. Then replicate the history that was on the branch on the original branch following the amended revision. This way the file is _not_ part of the history of the _rewritten_ branch.

Comment: I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge with GIT. I'm much more of a 'visual' learner, so if anyone can reference some good GIT Video Tutorials for me to follow and learn more... it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks @Edmundo for pointing me in the right direction! Again, I'm barely a Git Beginner, so any specific directions or references to any walkthroughs would be greatly appreciated as I am not familiar with how to 'amend' or 'replicate' a branch.

Comment: Well.... can you identity the revision where the file was added? Set a branch on that revision... something like: ```git branch corrected-branch the-rev-id```. Now you have created a branch at that point. Check it out: ```git checkout corrected-branch```. The file that is +100 MBs is be right in front of you, right? Remove it from the revision: ```git rm --cache file-path.txt```. Amend the revision: ```git commit --amend --no-edit```. Now replicate the history of the original branch: ```git cherry-pick the-rev-id..original-branch``` (the-rev-id is the id you used on git branch before)

Comment: The defacto standard tool for accident cleanup: [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)

Comment: @Edmundo thanks for the helpful information getting me this far. I think I am getting close. I created a new branch, removed the cached files, amended, then tried to cherry-pick and it wouldn't let me merge because of the untracked working tree files would be overwritten (which is strange because I thought I removed them).

Comment: Well.... I guess you could stash them and pop them out when done if they are important? Don't know how important they are for you